# Index of list item ul li when click on link inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, onclick

I was reading a lot of questions here about getting value of index.

I know how to get `li` on click index number. However, I need to get the `li` value when the link within it is clicked.

```
<ul>
   <li><a class=link href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class=link href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class=link href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a class=link href="#"></a></li>
</ul>


$("li a.link").click(function(e) {
    var i = $(this).index();
       alert(i)
});
```

It won't work because it takes the index of `a.link` not `ul li`. How can I get index of the `li` when a specific `a.link` is clicked?

Comment: $(this).parent().index();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector to target the index of the parent element of the clicked anchor link.

In this case, it would be: `$(this).parent().index();`.

```
$("li a.link").click(function(e) {
    var i = $(this).parent().index();
    alert(i);
});
```

If you want to get the physical number (e.g. first returns one, second returns two), you'd just add one to the selector:

```
$("li a.link").click(function(e) {
    var i = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    alert(i);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply both of them doesnt work, in first case it shows 2 or 3 all the time doesnt matter which 'code'li'code' I click.

Comment: YEs it is - sorry i just wrote anwser. Cuz it works on showed case my was different. After all your anwser was good and helped my to solve my problem. THANK YOU :)

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński Ah I thought so :) No worries man, glad to help any time!

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take: count which position the clicked li is, or number them beforehand. The second is much more efficient (constant time on a click):

```
var li_elems = $('li.link'),
    i = 0,
    len = li_elems.length;

for (; i < len; i++) {
   li_elems[i].attr('index', i);
}

$('ul').on('click', 'li.link', function (e) {
  var index = this.getAttribute('index');
  alert(index);
});
```