# How to get index from html:select component?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

```
Page code:
---------

 <html:select property="projectId" styleClass="ctrlwidthfirstpair">
    <html:options  collection="projects" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
 </html:select>
```

### JavaScript:

```
function isProjectSelected() {
    var selIndex = document.getElementById("projectId").selectedIndex;
    if (selIndex == 0) {
        alert("Please Select Project");
        return false;
    }
    return true;  
}
```

`document.getElementById("projectId")` returns `null` value.

How to get index of selected option of `<html:select>` component?

Comment: What's the language/framework you are using?  Try <html:select property="projectId" id="projectId"  :)

Comment: Check this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778214/index-of-list-item-ul-li-when-click-on-link-inside

Comment: html:select component hasn't id property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute you're looking for is `styleId`. Next time, try [reading the fine manual](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/html/select.html).

```
<html:select styleId="projectId" ...
```

Comment: i am checking whether any project is selected or not.

Comment: i dont have rights to downvote,,,may be someone else

Answer (score 0):

All html tags in Struts **styleId** property will be rendered as id attribute.
Try like that..

```
<html:select property="projectId" styleId="projectId" styleClass="ctrlwidthfirstpair">
<html:options  collection="projects" property="value" labelProperty="label" />
```